# New Outlook for Mac (v16.44) & Applescript

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I am trying to migrate a number of AppleScripts to the new Outlook for Mac.

A basic task is to retrieve selected messages.

I have been using for years

`set msgSet to selection`

.. but this does not work with the new Outlook -- it returns `(*missing value*)`.

Same with
`set msgSet to current messages`.

Any thoughts on what might be the reason?

Thanks!

Giovanni

Comment: The reason might be that Microsoft changed the Applescript dictionary of Outlook with that version update. You might be better served looking for the details on the Apple script-ability of Outlook on the Microsoft knowledge base or discussion forums.

Comment: thanks @SteveChambers. I did that and they mentioned that AppleScript is "not supported yet in the new Outlook experience", even though a new dictionary exists. I also learned that there is an [astonishing number](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/924856) of bugs and issues with the new outlook, so if others use applescript a lot, beware before switching ☠!